# What's a word for a dragon who eats only nonintelligent animals?

Tags: food, dragons

I want to run an adventure in which the heroes encounter a bronze dragon.  She wants to reassure them that she's not going to eat them, so she says: "Don't worry, I'm a stupidtarian!"  (An eater of only stupid things, ie, nonsapient animals.)

What's a better word than "stupidtarian"?  A good word should have an intuitively obvious definition (meaning the characters don't have to immediately ask the dragon to define the word), and also should sound less dumb than "stupidtarian".

Comment: You could just be looking for the alignments. A *lawful good* dragon would not eat intelligent beings

Comment: Does the word need to be immediately understandable to the players? I don't think such a word already exists.

Comment: Might it not be easier for the dragon to say: **"Don't worry, I don't eat _sapient_ beings!"** and leave it at that? Also keep in mind that a raven is intelligent, as well as sentient. This goes double for dolphins or elephants. However we are the only sapient species on the planet, which is, I think, what you really wanted to get that. All this being said, I really don't think this is a Worldbuilding SE question ...

Comment: @AndreiROM I agree that that would be easier, but it says interesting things about draconic culture if they actually have a word for it.  Good point about sapient, though, I changed my wording above.

Comment: I would use the term "ethical carnivore."

Comment: @Neil yes! Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you might like words like nonsapienstarian, nonsentienstarian.

Maybe your dragon is the kind of dragon to say "don't worry, my snack don't actually USE their brain" or something like that.

but it's not really a worldbuilding question, but more of a question about linguistics and about what your character could say...

Comment: Please don't answers questions that you can clearly identify as off-topic. Instead, leave a comment to the OP and flag the question to bring it to the attention of those who can handle it properly.

Comment: ok, got it. I'm new, so thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I do like nonsapientarian, but I would like it more if it didn't have that "non" in it. What's the antonym for "sapient"?...  Still, +1, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Terry Pratchett's books mention a sect of vampires who wear a [black ribbon](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Black_Ribbon). This ribbon is proof they have signed a treaty stating they won't drink blood.

I think making a system like that is fine, and something like:

"*Do not fear; I am a Noble Dragon, I have taken the Oath*"

Makes a less comical statement than :

"*lol dw guys I'm stupidtarian*".

Answer (score 1):

My first thought when I saw this question was “Narnian”,
in reference to [*The Chronicles of Narnia* by C. S. Lewis](https://www.narnia.com), where

- some animals can talk, and are treated as people
  who happen to be of a species other than human, and
- some animals cannot talk, and are treated as ordinary animals,
  suitable for hunting or slaughter.

A slightly more esoteric term would be “Muppet” (or “Muppetian”?),
in reference to *The Muppets*, in which the same paradigm applies —
Gonzo’s chickens are just animals, but the frog, the pig, the bear,
the eagle, etc., are people who just happen not to be human.